# CAS WAR Overlay Project - REST APIs added in custom java class giving 404

Tags: cas

I am working to add a custom functionality to **CAS WAR Overlay Project v6.1.6** where I created a REST Controller class in src/main/java folder as suggested in CAS documentation:

"In order to include custom Java source, it should be included under a src/main/java directory in the overlay project source tree."

So i included my java class which is a REST Controller at this location for e.g.: src/main/java/com/example/rest/RestController.class

However, when I run my overlay project in intellij using the command ./gradlew run and try the APIs in Postman then i get 404. Am i missing something here?

This is the link where CAS explains about the ability to customise is below:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/WAR-Overlay-Installation.html#custom-and-third-party-source

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing here the response I received from Ray Bon in CAS Google Groups
https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/d/msg/cas-user/SDR38-smzKE/Z9SacX6ACAAJ

In my case, I had to configure my custom class as define it as a Bean in CasRestConfiguration.java and also inject whatever dependencies it requires.

Also, it is important to note that as per CAS REST Support module API endpoints have to be routed through "/v1/" prefix or else they wont be identified.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Nevertheless, I tested this with CAS 6.2.2 and it looks like there is no need to register your Spring MVC controller bean via the `CasRestConfiguration` (just use your own config class), neither to stick to the `/v1/` path prefix. But YMMV...